# When should I use an EitherT[Future]

Tags: scala, scalaz

Let's consider a concrete example : methods on my repository that return `Future` (because there is a call to a remote database that takes time and may fail)

```
def findA(id: String) : Future[Option[String]] = ???
def findB(id: String) : Future[Option[String]] = ???
```

And I need a service that combines them. Moreover, there is a business rule : *both ids must correspond to existing objects and if not, the program must fail fast with a comprehensive error*.

I have basically 2 options :

**Using only `Future`**

```
  def findAll(idA: String, idB: String): Future[(String, String)] =
    for {
      a <- findA(idA).flatMap(_.fold(Future.failed[String](new RuntimeException("a not found")))(s => Future.successful(s)))
      b <- findB(idB).flatMap(_.fold(Future.failed[String](new RuntimeException("b not found")))(s => Future.successful(s)))
    } yield (a, b)
```

**Using `EitherT`**

```
  def findAll(idA: String, idB: String): DisjunctionT[Future, String, (String, String)] =
    for {
      a <- EitherT(findA(idA).map(_.\/>("a not found")))
      b <- EitherT(findB(idB).map(_.\/>("b not found")))
    } yield (a, b)
```

With `EitherT`, I see 2 pros

- we don't mix together technical and functional issues
- we don't have to wrap the error into an Exception

Are there any other pros and cons ?

Comment: Related - https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/3r5ii6/on_handling_futureeithera_b_sequencing/